# FormGroup Required condicionado

Tags: angular

Tenho um `component` de endereço ao qual possui um `form`, este sera `requirido` em alguns lugares e outros não então pretendo utilizar uma variavel `@input required = false;` para fazer isso.

Eu inicializo o formGroup no onInit  assim:

```
     buildForm(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      cep: [
        '', [
          Validators.required
        ]
      ],
      uf: [
        '', [
          Validators.required
        ]
      ],
}
```

Esse são alguns dos campos:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uf" class="required">UF:</label>
    <ss-dropdown formControlName="uf" (onChange)="onChangeUf($event.value)" class="component" [options]="ufs" label="label" value="value"></ss-dropdown>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.uf" class="form-errors">
      {{ formErrors.uf }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-14 col-md-14 col-sm-14">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cidade" class="required">Município:</label>
    <p-autoComplete id="cidade" minLength="5" formControlName="cidade" class="component"></p-autoComplete>
    <div *ngIf="formErrors.cidade" class="form-errors" maxlength="50">
      {{ formErrors.cidade }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E assim chamo meu component :

```
 <ss-endereco #endereco [endereco]="cliente?.endereco"></ss-endereco>
```

como faço para deixar o required dinamico neste caso?

Comment: Removi a tag  `angularjs`, uma vez que essa tag representa a versão 1 do angular e a dúvida é em relação a versão mais recente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Input` é construído através de um [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding):

```
<ss-endereco #endereco 
             [endereco]="cliente?.endereco" 
             [required]="false">
</ss-endereco>
```

No script do componente, você pode inicializar o `Input` com um valor `true` por exemplo:

```
@Input required = true;
```

Sendo assim, quando nenhum valor for informado, será assumido `true` para a variável `required`.

Para adicionar o `Validators.required` dinamicamente, basta utilizar a variável `required`:

```
 buildForm(): void {
     let validators = [];

     if(this.required)
         validators.push(Validators.required);

     this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
         cep: ['', validators],
         uf: ['', validators]
     })
     //...
 }
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui

Comment: estou recebendo um erro, `inline template:6:94 caused by: v is not a function` , acho que e na construição do formGroup, fiz como você, tem ideia do que seja?

Comment: acho que o problema e na forma que  validators e declarado, vou fazer  algumas verificações.

Comment: Teve um pequena alteração para funcionar mas a ideia e essa

Comment: @WilliamCézar e qual foi essa alteração? Assim posso completar a resposta e ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Ok, logo posto aqui, muito obrigado pela ajuda Felipe